# Prepend only if does not have already

Tags: jquery

I need to prepend an element to a text withing an element on click, BUT only once, if it does not exist withing that element.

```
$('.myEm').prepend('<span class="prependMe"></span>');
```

I'd rather avoid if else construct. I've tried this but it did not work for me:

```
$('.myEm:not(.prependMe)').prepend('<span class="prependMe"></span>');
```

Stuck...

Comment: Could you post your HTML?

Comment: Sorry about wrong closing tag. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Forgot to fix it in the first code block too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to use `:has`

```
$(".myEm:not(:has(.prependMe))").prepend("<span></span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 '<span class="prependMe"></i>'
```

Should be

```
 '<span class="prependMe"></span>'
```

Use `:not()` and `:has()` as in the following:

```
 $('.myEm:not(:has(span.prependMe))').prepend( '<span class="prependMe"></span>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Santa I don't understand why you are closing a  tag with an  tag. This little things might cause unexpected bugs in your code.

However, this solves your problem

$('.myEm').not($('.myEm').has('span.prependMe')).prepend('...');

See the docs http://api.jquery.com/not/
             http://api.jquery.com/has/